# Vue.js method called multiple times using $emit and $on when it should only be called once

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I'm using a bus to allow components to interact with other components via the method described in this link: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/create-event-bus-in-webpack-template/4546/2  .

I have a method that is called in created hook which uses the bus to emit an event.

```
created () {
  this.getReviewDeck()
},
myMethod () {
    bus.$emit('increment')
}
```

In another component (which is contained in the above component) I attach the event listener in the created hook as below:

```
created () {
  bus.$on('increment', this.incrementCount)
},
incrementCount () {
  console.log('count incremented')
}
```

If I visit the component the first time everything works properly and the console will log 'count incremented' one time. However, if I leave the component and then navigate back to it the next time 'count incremented' will be logged twice, and if I leave and come back again it will now be logged three times etc.

I can't quite figure out what exactly is going on or how best to solve this issue so that every time I go to the component the message is only logged once instead of multiple times.

Comment: how do you setup the bus? Maybe you define it multiple times? I usually add the bus to the Vue component prototype in the bootstrap of the application. This will ensure you don't define it multiple times. As a frist "debugging step" you should console log within your created method where you register on the bus to check how often it is called. It should only be called once.

Comment: what do you mean by "leave/visit the component"?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Had to remove the event handler on destroy.

```
 beforeDestroy () {
    EventBus.$off('increment', this.incrementCount)
 },
```

Comment: somehow @dpst's solution didn't work well in my case, it triggered a fixed three times once I added `bus.$off` to `beforeDestory`.

At this time I just added `bus.$off` at the end of the function and call it a day.

Comment: In my own project I used the `destroyed` event instead of `beforeDestroy`.

Comment: I think the post on this link should be read together with this answer. Its a great explanation (for better understanding) of the duplicate event listeners issue: https://charlietheprogrammer.com/duplicate-vue-event-listeners-and-how-i-solved-them

Answer (score 11):

You can use $.once

```
created () {
  bus.$once('increment', this.incrementCount)
},
```

Answer (score 9):

Seems like something changed in Vue source code, as turning off eventBus listeners in destroyed or beforeDestroy or beforeRouteLeave or any other hooks does the following - old listeners are deleted together with new listeners that are re-registered in created hook.

For destroyed and beforeDestroy hooks it's understandable as they are called after created hook. So created() adds listeners, and destroyed() deletes them all, not only those from previous created(). But for route hooks I don't understand the behavior, as they are called before created() but all the same re-registered listeners do not work.

What I did is turning off eventBus listeners in created hook before re-registering them

```
created() {
  eventBus.$off("someListener");
  eventBus.$on("someListener", () => {
    // do smth
  })
}
```

But this works only if component is re-created, it it's created only once during app lifecycle, the registered listener will not work. But if the component is created once we do not need this re-registering.

Comment: This worked for me. Seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and none of the above mentioned answers worked for me. 
I solved this issue by adding eventBus as a Vue Global Instance

Adding this in the main.js file

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

And calling it in the components like:

```
   mounted(){
    this.$bus.$on('chatData', (data) => {
        console.log('receieved in component');
    });
   },
   beforeDestroy() {
    this.$bus.$off('chatData');
   },
   methods:{
    sendData(data){
     this.$bus.$emit('someData',data); 
    }
   }
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. although the above solutions are correct, in my case, I wasn't leaving the component, so beforeDestroy was not relevant and events still triggered twice and more...

Comment: So are you not turning the events off?

Comment: Adding events as a Vue Global Instance as you mentioned helped me in the case the event fired twice in my component since I wasn't leaving it... but still turning them off before destroy when eventually component is left...

Answer (score 4):

To remove all listeners:

```
this.$eventBus.$off()
```

Add this in your beforeDestroy() event of your main component lifecycle.

```
beforeDestroy() {
   this.$bus.$off('chatData');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in the case if you want to perform an action only once after the event is emitted. What if you want to keep listening for an event, for eg: if you hover over a data point on a graph you want to trigger some action of other component. 
In that case using $once doesn't work. 
I am facing same problem where I emit an event on a hover and its subscribed using $on, it should get called only once but in my case its getting called multiple times.

This is how I emit the event;

```
this.$eventBus.$emit("SHOW_HOVERLINE", d);
```

This is how I am subscribing the event;

```
this.$eventBus.$on("SHOW_HOVERLINE", this.someFunction);
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23652950)

Comment: sure. I will add this as a question